# How to retrieve the thumbnail rotation

Tags: android, picasso

I am creating a sort of 'Gallery' app that is displaying all the images in a grid.

**The issue is:**  that some of the images are not displayed in the right orientation.

Here is the code to retrieve the thumbnails

```
final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID };
//query the thumbnails provider
Cursor thumbnailsCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
            null, null);
if (thumbnailsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            //get the thumbnail path
            fullPath = thumbnailsCursor.getString(fullPathColumnIndex);
            thumbnailUri = Uri.parse(fullPath);
            //add the uri to the list
            thumbnailsList.add(thumbnailUri);
}  while (thumbnailsCursor.moveToNext());
thumbnailsCursor.close();
```

Inside the `getView()` of the `BaseAdapter` I am using `Picasso` image loader library to display the thumbnail, but sometimes the orientation is wrong.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(photoItem.thumbnail.getPath())).noFade().into(holder.photoImageView);
```

I have tried querying the real photo data and retrieve the orientation but the process is too slow( couple of seconds long) and the displayed images are too large.

Comment: is problem solved???

Answer (score 13):

Given the ID of the image you can query the MediaStore to get the path to the original image, and then grab the exif for the orientation from there.

This process is quite fast, and usually only takes a few milliseconds.

```
 Cursor cursor =
          CustomApplication
              .getContext()
              .getContentResolver()
              .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                  new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?",
                  new String[] {"" + PHOTO_ID}, null);
      if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String fullPath = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(fullPath);
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        //ROTATE AND FLIP YOUR THUMBNAIL AS NEEDED BASED ON exifOrientation
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct solution. You can query the orientation data from MediaStore so use 
MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION to get orientation degreee.

```
 final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };

 Cursor thumbnailsCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
if (thumbnailsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
  int orientationColumnIndex    =   thumbnailsCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION);
  int orientation = cur.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
//do what you want to do with orientation value
}while (thumbnailsCursor.moveToNext());
 thumbnailsCursor.close();
```

will give you the orientation in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ExifInterface class as follows:

```
int originalOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

try {
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoItem.thumbnail.getPath().toString());
    originalOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can check if it is rotated and do whatever logic you need (such as passing in a rotate angle to the Picasso request).

```
if (originalOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 || originalOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
    //do something
}
```

This is the method I use and I have never noticed any performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you can apply custom transformations for your loading task in picasso lib.

here is [solution](https://gist.github.com/dnkoutso/9e34a1bba3d63034e863) refer it.

at there **transform** method is using **MATRIX** same as other have given ansewer..

i have not checked yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static float getOrientationValue(String location) {
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(new File(location).getAbsolutePath());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    int rotate = 0;
    switch (orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate += 90;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate += 90;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate += 90;
    }
    return rotate;
    }
```

or

```
  public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
```